# can't load picture from camera/dropbox

Tags: java, android

With this function I can only load pictures from gallery, but I can't upload pictures from file system or from Dropbox, or get acquire them from camera:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:

            this.picturePath = picturePath;

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AndroidPaint.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
           Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            this.picturePath = picturePath;
            cursor.close();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AndroidPaint.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            //  doCrop();

            break;


    }
}
```

If anyone has got a suggestion please help me, I want to upload pictures from all settings.

Problem is here:

> ```
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/appSetpaint4fun.png typ=image/png }} to activity {com.slikar.slika/slikar.Main.FirstPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3103)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3146)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:132)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1187)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at slikar.Main.FirstPage.onActivityResult(FirstPage.java:396)
>     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3099)
>     ... 11 more
> ```

The error is in this section of code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this class I found online

```
public class BrowsePicture extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                    // select a file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

}
```

Comment: eror is now there:  int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

Comment: same as first eror:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/appSetpaint4fun.png typ=image/png }} to activity {com.slikar.slika/slikar.Main.FirstPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: see ** who=null ** and ** java.lang.NullPointerException ** so the object u r wanting is a null. try different picture

Comment: hmm problem is why its work from galery but not from dropbox and other,. and in other aplication i can load picture.